# Import .dll for NWJS module causes '#import of type library is an unsupported Microsoft feature'

Tags: c++, node.js, node-webkit, node-gyp

I have a legacy module for our app. It uses external dll from other software. If I run this command

```
 nw-gyp rebuild --target=0.34.3 --msvs_version=2019 --target_arch=ia32 --arch=ia32
```

it produces some warnings, but compiles (where 0.34.3 is a nw.js version)

But if I run this command

```
nw-gyp rebuild --target=0.68.0 --msvs_version=2019 --target_arch=ia32 --arch=ia32
```

I receive following errors

```
clang-cl : warning : argument unused during compilation: '/Gm-' [-Wunused-command-line-argument] 
clang-cl : warning : argument unused during compilation: '/external:W3' [-Wunused-command-line-argument] 
..\src\atol8.cpp(2,2): error : #import of type library is an unsupported Microsoft feature 
..\src\atol8.cpp(27,2): error : unknown type name 'CLSID' 
..\src\atol8.cpp(28,2): error : unknown type name 'IDispatch' 
..\src\atol8.cpp(29,2): error : use of undeclared identifier 'FprnM1C' 
..\src\atol8.cpp(30,2): error : unknown type name 'DISPPARAMS'
```

As I understand, main error is that compiler can't import external library, throws `#import of type library is an unsupported Microsoft feature` and it causes other errors.

```
atol8.cpp code

#import "D:\Program Files (x86)\ATOL\Drivers8\Bin\FprnM1C.dll" raw_interfaces_only

#include <node.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <string>
#include <wchar.h>

std::locale ru("rus_rus.1251");

namespace Atol8Drv {

using v8::Exception;
using v8::FunctionCallbackInfo;
using v8::Isolate;
using v8::Local;
using v8::Number;
using v8::Object;
using v8::String;
using v8::Value;
using v8::HandleScope;
using v8::Array;
using v8::Integer;
using v8::Boolean;

CLSID clsid;
IDispatch *pWApp;
FprnM1C::IFprnM45 *pMiDrv;
/** other code is not relevant **/
```

I am not a C programmer and the person who originally wrote this module is not available, but as I remember there should be a parameter for the nw-gyp or node-gyp and I can't nor remember or google how to resolve this error.

I'm ready to answer your questions and provide additional information if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a way to compile this module. The problem is in `clang`.

If I try to compile it with `--clang=false` option - it works perfectly.

So, if someone in the future will stuck with the same error, command for compilation should be:

```
nw-gyp rebuild --target=0.68.0 --msvs_version=2019 --target_arch=ia32 --arch=ia32 --clang=false
```